# React-native image - unknown named module '../img/2.jpeg'

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to modify a react-redux tutorial code. I'm trying to load images that are stored locally and the paths are saved in an object.

```
...
{
    "id": 2,
    "title": "Redux",
    "subtitle": "A State of Mind",
    "img": "../img/3.jpeg",
    "description": "Redux is a predictable state container for JavaScript apps. It helps you write applications that behave consistently, run in different environments (client, server, and native), and are easy to test."
  },
...
```

I have got the following error (I've restarted the simulator a few times)

> Unknown named module: '../img/3.jpeg'

Here's the container (eslint also says - unexpected require())

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  Text,
  TouchableWithoutFeedback,
  View,
  LayoutAnimation,
  Image
} from 'react-native';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { CardSection } from './common';
import * as actions from '../actions';

class ListItem extends Component {
  componentWillUpdate() {
    LayoutAnimation.spring();
  }

  renderDescription() {
    const { library, expanded } = this.props;

    if (expanded) {
      return (
        <CardSection>
          <Image
            source={require(library.img)}
            style={styles.imageStyle}
          />
          <View>
            <Text>{library.subtitle}</Text>
            <Text style={{ flex: 1 }}>
              {library.description}
            </Text>
          </View>
        </CardSection>
      );
    }
  }

  render() {
    const { titleStyle } = styles;
    const { id, title } = this.props.library;

    return (
      <TouchableWithoutFeedback
        onPress={() => this.props.selectLibrary(id)}
      >
        <View>
          <CardSection>
            <Text style={titleStyle}>
              {title}
            </Text>
          </CardSection>
          {this.renderDescription()}
        </View>
      </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
    );
  }
}

const styles = {
  titleStyle: {
    fontSize: 18,
    paddingLeft: 15
  },
  descriptionStyle: {
    paddingLeft: 10,
    paddingRight: 10
  },
  imageStyle: {
    height: 100,
    width: 100,
    backgroundColor: 'black'
  }
};

const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => {
  const expanded = state.selectedLibraryId === ownProps.library.id;

  return { expanded };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, actions)(ListItem);
```

Apart from the image, everything is working fine - just the image is not there.

Answer (score 1):

You can not dynamically require images in React Native, either do it statically, or use uri like this:

```
source={{ uri: library.img }}
```

But take in consideration the you have to put your images under this path

```
anroid/app/src/main/res/drawable
```

create `drawable` folder if it's not created.

and update the json file to remove the `../`

Please refer to this issue:  https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/2481

Comment: Thanks. That got rid of the errors but it renders empty blank spaces instead of images.

Comment: Thanks I'm doing it on ios, though.